# Filtering with WHERE based on whether a variable is a number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to filter a SELECT statament based on whether a variable is a number or not. The behavior I want is that if the parameter @productId is not a number then I want the WHERE clause to do the following:

```
WHERE (DTH.TaskId IS NULL OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId)
```

If @productId is a number I want the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (PDT.PK_Product = @productId)
```

I thought the following would work:

```
    WHERE (ISNUMERIC(@productId) = 0 AND DTH.TaskId IS NULL
            OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId)
    AND (ISNUMERIC(@productId) = 1 AND PDT.PK_Product = @productId)
```

because if ISNUMERIC(@productId) evaluates to 0 it would not use the second part of the statement and if 1 the first.

Edit:

The problem I have is that if productId is numeric (and ISNUMERIC(@productId) evaluates to 1) I am still getting results where DTH.TaskId IS NULL.

Comment: What does "not working however" mean?

Comment: I added a response above. Thanks for helping me clarify.

Comment: If your SELECT uses aggregation functions then this may be important: `CASE` does not reliably provide short circuit evaluation in the presence of aggregation functions.  See [CASE / COALESCE won't always evaluate in textual order
](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/690017/case-coalesce-wont-always-evaluate-in-textual-order) and [Aggregates Don't Follow the Semantics Of CASE
](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691535/aggregates-dont-follow-the-semantics-of-case ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE 1 =
  CASE ISNUMERIC(@productId)
    WHEN 0 THEN
      CASE WHEN DTH.TaskId IS NULL OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId THEN 1 END
    WHEN 1 THEN
      CASE WHEN DTH.TaskId IS NOT NULL AND PDT.PK_Product = @productId THEN 1 END
  END
```

Answer (score 2):

You need extra parentheses around the `OR` conditional, since `AND` takes precedence. You can't use `AND` between the conditional groups, because `@productId` can only be numeric or not, not both. You also need to filter out the `NOT NULL` values from the second conditional. So:

```
WHERE 
(
  ISNUMERIC(@productId) = 0 AND 
  (
    DTH.TaskId IS NULL
    OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId
  ) -- <-- these parens are important
)
OR -- <-- this can't be AND - @productId can't be numeric and not numeric
(
  ISNUMERIC(@productId) = 1 
  AND DTH.TaskID IS NOT NULL -- <-- this clause is important according to edit
  AND PDT.PK_Product = @productId
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are close, this should do the trick

```
WHERE (ISNUMERIC(@productId) = 1 AND PDT.PK_Product = @productId AND DTH.TaskId IS NOT NULL) OR
      (ISNUMERIC(@productId) = 0 AND (DTH.TaskId IS NULL OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId))
```

Comment: I am still getting the same results where when @productId is a number I am getting back rows where DTH.TaskId IS NULL

Comment: @DavidTunnell the query above explicitly excludes cases where `DTH.TaskId IS NULL`, if you have some sample data, I can look at it to see what the exact issue is, but the query above should work, notice this at the end of first group in the where clause, `AND DTH.TaskId IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need another set of parenthesis and change the AND to OR

```
WHERE (ISNUMERIC(@productId) = 0 AND (DTH.TaskId IS NULL
        OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId))
OR (ISNUMERIC(@productId) = 1 AND PDT.PK_Product = @productId AND DTH.TaskId IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I am still getting the same results where when @productId is a number I am getting back rows where DTH.TaskId IS NULL

Comment: Edited to add the NOT NULL to the second portion of the WHERE.